# QIODevice::read(QFile, path): device not open

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm new in qt, I'm trying to read a text file and put it into a text browser. I created the button and the text browser, when I clicked the button I want that the content of the file is put into the text browser. This is the method used on the mainwindow:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
QFile file(C:\\Users\\branda\\Desktop\\Tools.txt");

if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    QMessageBox::information(0, "info", file.errorString());

QTextStream in(&file);

ui->textBrowser->setText(in.readAll()); }
```

The error message: "QIODevice::read (QFile, "??C:\Users\branda\Desktop\Tools.txt"): device not open".

The message box says: "The file name, directory name or volume label syntax incorrect".
Which is not, because I copied the path from the file property.

The main.cpp file is still the same as when it was created.

Comment: Your file path is missing a quote, though I don't think that's your problem since it would probably fail to compile. Also, the fact that the error message has two question marks in the path makes me think you accidentally pasted some non-printable characters. Try this: delete the entire path and retype it by hand so you know exactly what characters are getting in there.

Comment: Yes the missing quote was a typo, I'm sorry. So: i rewrite the path and it just worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a " at the begining of the dir string;

```
QFile file(C:\\Users\\branda\\Desktop\\Tools.txt");
```

Try this:

```
   QFile file("C:/Users/branda/Desktop/Tools.txt");
```